# symfony 2 form entity type persisting to database value is 0

Tags: database, forms, symfony

in my project i have manytomany relation between balance and cagegory table and card is join table, bellow is my code

```
 Entity/Balance
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Card", mappedBy="balance")
 */
protected $cards;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer")
 */
protected $categories;


-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Entity/Category
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Card", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $cards;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Entity/Card
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="cards")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Balance", inversedBy="cards")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="balance_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $balance;
```

so when I want to create a balance record i should select it is belong to which category,so i try to use form entity type to fetch data from category entity and persist category id to Balance table (category_id).

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('value')
        ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'myBundle:Category',
            'property' => 'name',
        ))
    ;
}
```

the data store but the value of category_id is 0 ????

Comment: Does the balance have one and only one category? If so you need a ManyToOne in the Balance record with Category as the target entity.

Comment: Thank you Alberto it is working now :)